# What is the best way to delegate UIButtons,UITextFields etc?

Tags: cocoa-touch, storyboard

In all my apps I am delegating all my UIButtons,UITextField,pickers etc.I am able to delegate these by 3 ways.
1-I am simply control+dragging the buttons,text field etc from the story board to the .h file which creates the delegation directly.
2-In .h file I am creating the buttons,text fields etc and then making the connections.
3-Programmatically doing the delegations

I want to know which is the best way to do it.

Comment: Simply choose the method you like most.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way is to use storyboard for referencing outlets and delegates. If you are not able to use storyboards then you do by codding. Storyboards will save your time of codding there is no major difference then this.

Answer (score 0):

> That is depending on you,you can do any way based on your
>   requirement,but Final result is same for all three methods.
>
> if you want to create dynamic labels and buttons at that time you must
>   use programatical method because you don't have any other solution
>   ,like that you can do it by your choice based on your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

They are equivalent. It's the same question as "is it better to write my UI programmatically or design it with Interface Builder?". The end result is the same; you should think about Interface Builder as simply a convenience tool and mechanism for creating interfaces and logic quickly. And if you need, you can mix both methods without problems.

When you drag your control from the IB sheet to your controller's code, you're creating a target-action association that is stored in the .xib file. When the .xib file is unpacked at runtime, your controls are created and their connections are restored, the same as if you did that programmatically.